# Cloning a complex hierarchical entity in typeorm

Tags: mysql, node.js, generics, typeorm, clone

What is the easiest/best way to clone a complex hierarchical entity with typeorm?
The main issue is with ids (main entity ids and foreign key ids), which need to be re-generated for the new object.
I tried implementing a generic "clone" operation, but it's insufficient:

1. load the entity from the DB
2. delete all ids from the object recursively (assumes object id property is named `id`)
3. save the object to the db

As said it's not enough since this only deletes the main object ids, but doesn't deal with foreign key properties which can have various names depending on the relation names.
One option is to implement a non-generic clone for each of the entities in the model hierarchy, which is not very elegant code, and will require maintenance each time new entities/foreign keys are added.
Any other suggestions?